# Setting first instance of a backbone array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is a dumb question that I should know the answer to, but my brain has turned to mush. So some help is needed! :)

I have a backbone array that kind of looks like this

```
this.something.get('MemberInfo').get('Images')
```

and then under that would be [0], [1], [2] and so on

We have a function that is removing all of those images so they can start anew and then they can add their first image.

I am having issues adding that first value back to the array. It keeps saying that [0] does not exist which is true because I am trying to create it. :)

I've tried

```
this.something.get('MemberInfo').get('Images')[0]set("ImagePath", image.FileName)


this.something.get('MemberInfo').get('Images')[0]set({"ImagePath": image.FileName})
```

and a few other fails. Some help would be appreciated. My brain is rocks in head today.

Comment: When you say that `this.something.get('MemberInfo').get('Images')` is a "backbone array" do you mean that it is an instance of [Backbone.Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection)?

Comment: You miss dot before `set`: `this.something.get('MemberInfo').get('Images')[0].set("ImagePath", image.FileName)`